# Countdown timer, need to convert days to hours

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer with days, hours, minutes and seconds. I want to remove days. Need to convert days to hours.

I tried to do it by myself, but no success because of lack of knowledge.

```
    (function(){
    $.fn.lofCountDown = function( options ) {
        return this.each(function() { 
            // get instance of the lofCountDown.
            new  $.lofCountDown( this, options ); 
        });
     }
    $.lofCountDown = function( obj, options ){
        this.options = $.extend({
                autoStart           : true,
                LeadingZero:true,
                DisplayFormat:"<div>%%D%% Days</div><div>%%H%% Hours</div><div>%%M%% Minutes</div><div>%%S%% Seconds</div>",
                FinishMessage:"Expired",
                CountActive:true,
                TargetDate:null
        }, options || {} );
        if( this.options.TargetDate == null || this.options.TargetDate == '' ){
            return ;
        }
        this.timer  = null;
        this.element = obj;
        this.CountStepper = -1;
        this.CountStepper = Math.ceil(this.CountStepper);
        this.SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(this.CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
        var dthen = new Date(this.options.TargetDate);
        var dnow = new Date();
        if( this.CountStepper > 0 ) {
            ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
        }
        else {
             ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
        }
        gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000); 
        this.CountBack(gsecs, this);
    };
     $.lofCountDown.fn =  $.lofCountDown.prototype;
     $.lofCountDown.fn.extend =  $.lofCountDown.extend = $.extend;
     $.lofCountDown.fn.extend({
        calculateDate:function( secs, num1, num2 ){
              var s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
              if ( this.options.LeadingZero && s.length < 2) {
                    s = "0" + s;
              }
              return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
        },
        CountBack:function( secs, self ){
             if (secs < 0) {
                self.element.innerHTML = '<div class="lof-labelexpired"> '+self.options.FinishMessage+"</div>";
                return;
              }
              clearInterval(self.timer);
              DisplayStr = self.options.DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, self.calculateDate( secs,86400,100000) );
              DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,3600,24));
              DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,60,60));
              DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,1,60));
              self.element.innerHTML = DisplayStr;
              if (self.options.CountActive) {
                   self.timer = null;
                 self.timer =  setTimeout( function(){
                    self.CountBack((secs+self.CountStepper),self);          
                },( self.SetTimeOutPeriod ) );
             }
        }           
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line that says:

```
DisplayFormat:"<div>%%D%% Days</div><div>%%H%% Hours</div><div>%%M%% Minutes</div><div>%%S%% Seconds</div>",
```

To read:

```
DisplayFormat:"<div>%%H%% Hours</div><div>%%M%% Minutes</div><div>%%S%% Seconds</div>",
```

Then change the line that says:

```
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,3600,24));
```

To read:

```
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,3600,876581));
```

Comment: One more question. How to separate hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: The variable `DisplayFormat` controls how the countdown is displayed. `%%H%%` = Hours, `%%M%%` = Minutes, `%%S%%` = Seconds. To set it to a format of hours:minutes:seconds you'd set the `DisplayFormat` variable to `%%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%%`.

Comment: i tried it, but script is more complex and has 4 more files. Now i did what i wanted. Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: I'm back again :D Strange, but calculations are wrong now :(
i changed line to DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,1800,876581));

if timer is set to one day, than time is displayed correctly, but if i change settings to 2 days, than counter starts not from 48 hours but from 72.

Comment: Look again at my orignal answer. Hours should not be `self.calculateDate(secs,1800,876581)` it should be `self.calculateDate(secs,3600,876581)`

Comment: yes, i tried 3600,876581, but still wrong calculation :( thank you for patience :)

Comment: I tested it out, seems to be working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/H4vcE/

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for delay. yes, you are right. everything works fine. I think i forgot to clean smarty cache folder. Now everything is ok. Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by replacing

DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,3600,24));

to

DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, self.calculateDate(secs,3600,876581));

Thanks to Rusty Jeans :)